# LoadFrom and UnsafeLoadFrom fail when loading a winmd file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, clr, winmd

I am trying to load a .winmd file using Reflection in a C# 4.5 app (i'd like to read the metadata stored in it).

When using `Assembly.LoadFrom` and `Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom`, the assembly loading fails with an exception:

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///xxxxx.winmd' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not
>   supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

When using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` it succeeds.

What is the explanation for this behavior? and what is the proper way of loading a .winmd component to read its metadata?

Comment: It is not a real .NET assembly.  Since it only contains metadata, using ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom is the logical choice.

Comment: @HansPassant But how do you call the methods then?